# Linear Algebra Solution set equal to Span

Tags: linear-algebra, homogeneous-equation, span

I am confused on how to approach a certain question. It asks to find a collection of vectors $x_1,\ldots,x_p$ so that the solution set of equation $ax=0$ is equal to $\operatorname{span} \{x_1,\ldots x_p\}$

They give a matrix of what $A$ is. What I am doing at the moment is creating a augmented matrix with $A$ and zeros in the last column. After I row reduce the matrix, I get $x_2=-x_4$ and $x_3=0$. How can I get the solution set from my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You're seeking a basis for the [null space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28linear_algebra%29) of $A$.  If I understand correctly, you've reached the reduced row echelon form augmented matrix:
$$
\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c}
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}\right]
$$
(possibly with some extra rows of zeroes).  The solutions to this system of linear equations (i.e., the null space) has the form $$\mathrm{null}(A)=\{(\alpha,\beta,0,-\beta):\alpha,\beta \in K\}$$ (where $K$ is the underlying field).

We could alternatively write this $$\mathrm{null}(A)=\{\alpha(1,0,0,0)+\beta(0,1,0,-1):\alpha,\beta \in K\}$$ which should give you an idea of what's a good choice of basis for the null space.

Comment: could you please explain the null (a) I reached the echelon form you posted. I have x2=-x4 and x3=0. How did you get (1,0,0,0)+B(0,1,0,-1)?

Comment: There are two free variables: $x_1$ has no restrictions placed on it (so it is free), and $x_2$ can be considered free.  We know $x_3=0$, so it's not free, and $x_4$ is determined by $x_2$.  So, I set $x_1=\alpha$ and $x_2=\beta$.

Comment: Oh ok, so if there are no other extra rows with zeros. I can still   assume there are extra rows that have x1 and x2 free?

Comment: With or without additional rows of zeroes, the null space is the same.  It equivalent to adding the restriction $0=0$ (which makes no difference).  We must have $x_1$ free, since it's value does not affect whether or not $A \mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$.  We either have $x_2$ free (and $x_4$ is determined from it), or we can have $x_4$ free (and $x_2$ is determined from $x_4$).

Comment: ok so far I have x1=x1, x2=-x4, x3=0, x4=free. Shouldn't your vector with scalar B be (0,-1,0,1)?

Comment: That's essentially the same thing: we now have the arbitrary scalar replaced by its negative.

Answer (score 0):

Could you specify, what $A$ is or write the row-reduced form of $A$? Then your question will be clearer. Given that you have got the row-reduced form, you are just a step away from getting the vectors $x_1,\ldots, x_p$ such that they span the solution space of $AX = 0$

Comment: my row reduced form is what Rebecca posted above